# stanford corenlp: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model

Tags: java, eclipse, stanford-nlp

I need to use the StanfordTruecaser using the Java API. I have this code:

```
  String text = "i love paris. i am with barack obama";

  //define the properties of the pipeline to be run and add annotators to it
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, truecase");
  pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

  //run annotators on document text
  Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
  pipeline.annotate(document);
```

But the POS tagger doesn't work well:

```
Adding annotator pos
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Unrecoverable error while loading a tagger model
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP$4.create(StanfordCoreNLP.java:558)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:267)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:129)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:125)
```

I use Eclipse and I have linked the *stanford-corenlp-3.4.jar* like this:
[image]

Comment: No, how to do that ?

Comment: Did you also download the correct models.jar and add it to your classpath?

Comment: I forgot the models.jar. now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add the *stanford-corenlp-3.4-models.jar* to the classpath in Eclipse and it works.